# Access PHPMyadmin in Ubuntu

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I installed the LAMP stack [Apache2, Mysq, PHP] and phpmyAdmin for DB administration. All worked fine except when I open mysql in my terminal, it has different configurations than my phpmyadmin:

- The phpmyadmin and mysql-client have different credentials and contents

I want to work in my database queries in my terminal and reflect all the changes when I logged in my phpmyadmin. **How can I connect the two?**

Comment: What is different exactly, if its the password then change both to one form!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen they're somehow not connected to each other.  They're different users.

Comment: They should not be connected to each other - but both should use the same mysql server. Do you have more than one mysql server installed?

Comment: Then use database access right in mysql to both users for the database in question!